# ratio between heat transfer coefficient and thermal conductivity

Tags: biochemistry, mathematical-models, heat

Consider the Robin boundary condition for the diffusion/heat equation $\mathrm{u_t=a(t)u_{xx}+f(x,t)}$:

$$\mathrm{-k(t)u_x(0,t)=h(t)u(0,t)}$$

or

$$\mathrm{u_x(0,t)+\frac{h(t)}{k(t)}u(0,t)=0}$$

where $\mathrm{k(t)}$ thermal conductivity and $\mathrm{h(t)}$ heat tranfer coefficient.

My Question: Is it possible that the ratio $\mathrm{h(t)/k(t)}$ to be constant? Could anyone please help me? I have really no idea.

Comment: This is probably better suited to chemistry stack exchange as it smells like physical chemistry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited for physics

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you can't assume that $h/k$ might be constant. Reason is that those parameters are characteristics of two very separate systems.

Thermal conductivity shows how fast heat can be propagated through **material**. That is, it answers question: if block of metal has $T_0$ temperature on its surface A, and you apply temperature $T_1$ (higher) to opposite surface B, how long it will take for whole block to get to temperature $T_1$.

Heat transfer coefficient is a characteristic of a **system**. For example, when you have coolant on one side of metal plate, and heated air on the other. Question is how efficiently heat will be transferred from one side to the other. For more you can check [this link](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/overall-heat-transfer-coefficient-d_434.html). As you can see, transfer coefficient $U$ is a function of conductivity of the metal plate $k$. Hence, generally, relationship is non-linear.